# Django with urls.py in deployment

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have a problems. 
I have a *urls.py* like this:

```
  urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'views.home'),
    url(r'^archives/$', 'views.archives'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,}), 
    url('^contact/$', 'views.contact'),
    url('^about/$', 'views.about'),

    #blog
    url(r'^post/(?P<pid>\d+)/', 'blog.views.show_post'),
    url(r'^tag/(?P<name>.+)/$', 'blog.views.list_by_tag'),
    url(r'^feed/$', LatestPostFeed()),
    url(r'^upload-image/', 'blog.views.upload_image'),

)
```

Everything works fine when i test by built-in server, but it can't work when i deploy on server.

Using the URLconf defined in urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
^$
^archives/$
^admin/
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
^about/$
^post/(?P<pid>\d+)/
^tag/(?P<name>.+)/$
^feed/$
^upload-image/
The current URL, contact/, didn't match any of these.
```

According to these trace, i found 'contact' not in the urls order list, which i have already setted.
It confuses me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you've deployed the same urls.py you are showing? Also, try restarting the server.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine after restart server.